# how do you add businessHours on fullcalendar

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header:{
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            editable: false,
            selectable: true,
            allDaySlot: false,

            events: "index.php?view=1&owner=" + owner_userid,
            // so this is where i started to put the businessHours code
            businessHours: //so on this line i tried adding business hours 
            {

            start: '6:00', //start of business time
            end:   '24:00', //end of business time
            dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,0] //array that shows the days of the week 1 for monday 0 for sunday
            }
            //here is where it ends


            eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                endtime = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.end).format('h:mm');
                starttime = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format('dddd,MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm');
                var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
                $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
                $('#modalWhen').text(mywhen);
                $('#eventID').val(event.id);
                $('#calendarModal').modal();
            },
```

the calendar shows that my business time still starts at 12am but i want it to start at 6 how do i do this? ive already added the businessHours code so im sure im doing something wrong please help me.

Answer (score 0):

See a working demo:[SOURCE](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/businessHours/)

```js
$(function() {

 var todayDate = moment().startOf('day');
 var YM = todayDate.format('YYYY-MM');
 var YESTERDAY = todayDate.clone().subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
 var TODAY = todayDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
 var TOMORROW = todayDate.clone().add(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
   left: 'prev,next today',
   center: 'title',
   right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
  },
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  navLinks: true,
  businessHours: true,
  events: [
   {
    title: 'All Day Event',
    start: YM + '-01'
   },
   {
    title: 'Long Event',
    start: YM + '-07',
    end: YM + '-10'
   },
   {
    id: 999,
    title: 'Repeating Event',
    start: YM + '-09T16:00:00'
   },
   {
    id: 999,
    title: 'Repeating Event',
    start: YM + '-16T16:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Conference',
    start: YESTERDAY,
    end: TOMORROW
   },
   {
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: TODAY + 'T10:30:00',
    end: TODAY + 'T12:30:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Lunch',
    start: TODAY + 'T12:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: TODAY + 'T14:30:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Happy Hour',
    start: TODAY + 'T17:30:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Dinner',
    start: TODAY + 'T20:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Birthday Party',
    start: TOMORROW + 'T07:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Click for Google',
    url: 'http://google.com/',
    start: YM + '-28'
   }
  ],
   businessHours: {
    dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
    start: '6:00',
    end: '18:00'
} });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="https://fullcalendar.io/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="https://fullcalendar.io/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="https://fullcalendar.io/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="https://fullcalendar.io/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="https://fullcalendar.io/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="https://fullcalendar.io/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="https://fullcalendar.io/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="https://fullcalendar.io/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="https://fullcalendar.io/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://fullcalendar.io/favicon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://fullcalendar.io/favicon-160x160.png" sizes="160x160">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://fullcalendar.io/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://fullcalendar.io/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://fullcalendar.io/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2b5797">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://fullcalendar.io/mstile-144x144.png">

    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,400,700' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='https://fullcalendar.io/css/base.css?3.1.0-1.5.0-2' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css' />

   <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js'></script>
 <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>


<div id='calendar'></div>
```